# Can the error function be expressed in terms of other special functions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, complex

I obtained with  *Mathematica* some results written in terms of the error function **Erfi[x]**.

Is there is a way **to transform the error function into other special functions**  e.g. Bessel functions or others?

I wonder if it can be done with *Mathematica*.
Any suggestions are welcome.

U= Erfi[((1/2 + I/2) (R - z))/Sqrt[k R]] +   Erfi[((1/2 + I/2) (R - Sqrt[D^2 + z^2]))/Sqrt[k R]]

Comment: "The question is there is a way to transform the error function in terms of other special functions" - it can be expressed as e.g. an incomplete gamma function or a Kummer hypergeometric function, among [other possible representations](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Erfi/26/ShowAll.html). Otherwise, ***NO***.

Comment: What is the motivation of doing so?

Comment: Provide *Mathematica* expressions which returned the formula in the question. I guess there must be some misunderstanding since `D` is a function of the system.

Answer (score 5):

There are many identities reminding one in the question (unclear what kind of relation has been intended), e.g.  expressing `FresnelS` in terms of `Erfi`

```
FullSimplify[-1/4 (1 + I)( Erfi[(1 + I)Sqrt[Pi]z/2]- I Erfi[(1 - I)Sqrt[Pi]z/2])]
```

> ```
> FresnelS[z]
> ```

Let's demonstrate other relations:

```
FullSimplify[{-1/4 (1+I)(I  Erfi[(1+I)Sqrt[Pi]z/2]- Erfi[(1-I)Sqrt[Pi]z/2]),
              -(Sqrt[-z^2]/z) - (z/Sqrt[Pi]) ExpIntegralE[1/2, -z^2],
              (z/Sqrt[-z^2])(1 - (E^z^2/Sqrt[Pi])HypergeometricU[1/2, 1/2, -z^2])
              }]//Column
```

> ```
>   FresnelC[z]
>   Erfi[z]
>   Erfi[z]}
> ```

Such identities can be found exploiting `MathematicalFunctionData` and `MathematicalFunction` (the latter new in *version 12*), nontheless one can start with

```
MeijerGReduce[Erfi[x],x]
```

[image]

```
 Entity["MathematicalFunction","Erfi"]["AlternativeRepresentations"]
```

[image]
[image]

as well as

```
Entity["MathematicalFunction","Erfi"]["HypergeometricRepresentations"]
```

[image]

[image]

A **convenient** way of **exploring mathematical data** involves `Manipulate`, e.g.

```
Manipulate[ Entity["MathematicalFunction","Erfi"][z], 
            {z, Entity["MathematicalFunction","Erfi"]["Properties"]}]
```

various items of the following can yield other identities:

```
MathematicalFunctionData["Properties"]
```

[image]

Comment: No one of the above functions is an elementary function. I think it is impossible to reduce the `Erfi` function to elementary functions.

Answer (score 3):

```
U = Erfi[((1/2 + I/2) (R - z))/Sqrt[k R]] + 
   Erfi[((1/2 + I/2) (R - Sqrt[D^2 + z^2]))/Sqrt[k R]];
```

Use [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) to penalize the use of [`Erfi`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Erfi.html)

```
U2 = FullSimplify[U, 
  ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 
      1000 Count[#, _Erfi, {0, Infinity}] &)]

(* (1 + I) (FresnelC[(R - z)/(Sqrt[π] Sqrt[k R])] + 
   FresnelC[(R - Sqrt[D^2 + z^2])/(Sqrt[π] Sqrt[k R])] + 
   I (FresnelS[(R - z)/(Sqrt[π] Sqrt[k R])] + 
      FresnelS[(R - Sqrt[D^2 + z^2])/(Sqrt[π] Sqrt[k R])])) *)
```

The expressions are equivalent

```
U == U2 // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

However, you now have four special functions rather than two.

Comment: The OP has yet to respond, but this might be close to what is wanted, since at least the Fresnel integrals all take real arguments, even if the coefficients are complex.