# Roots of expressions involving the complementary error function

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I have an expression as follows

```
da = (ω (-((8 α)/Sqrt[ω]) + 4 E^(α^2/ω) Sqrt[π]
       Erfc[α/Sqrt[ω]] + (8 E^(α^2/ω)
       Sqrt[π] α^2 Erfc[α/Sqrt[ω]])/ω))/(-4 α Sqrt[ω] + 
   2 E^(α^2/ω)
     Sqrt[π] (2 α^2 + ω) Erfc[α/Sqrt[ω]]) - (ω (-4 Sqrt[ω] + 
     3 Sqrt[π] ω + 4 E^(α^2/ω)
       Sqrt[π] α Erfc[α/Sqrt[ω]]) (-4 Sqrt[ω] - (4 (2 α^2 + ω))/Sqrt[ω] + 
     8 E^(α^2/ω) Sqrt[π] α Erfc[α/Sqrt[ω]] + (4 E^(α^2/ω)
       Sqrt[π] α (2 α^2 + ω) Erfc[α/Sqrt[ω]])/ω))/(-4 α Sqrt[ω] + 
    2 E^(α^2/ω) Sqrt[π] (2 α^2 + ω) Erfc[α/Sqrt[ω]])^2
```

where $\omega$ is a positive real number. I intend to obtain the root of this expression so I tried

```
Solve[da == 0, α]
```

but it doesn't work and gives the following error

> ```
> This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
> ```

How can I get the roots?

Comment: I doubt that there is an analytical expression for your roots. Your best chances are numerical. This means that you will have to assign a numerical value for each parameter. Then you could try `NSolve`, but more likely you will need `FindRoot` with a reasonable choice of starting value.

Comment: @MarcoB But I need the analytical one! no idea?

Comment: *An analytical solution may not exist*. What would you need it for? There may be workarounds. Perhaps you solve numerically for a range of values of omega, then interpolate the results.

Comment: If each step of `Simplify[Numerator[Together[da]]/ω, ω>0]==0` can be justified then that gives you a MUCH smaller problem to solve, But you have to find some way to solve this which has α both inside and outside of Erfc and I don't see any way you are going to be able to do that. Maybe you can find a way.

Comment: Analytical root gives us insight, what a numerical one can't do.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Assume that both `ω` and `α` are positive

```
$Assumptions = ω > 0 && α > 0;

da = (ω (-((8 α)/Sqrt[ω]) + 
         4 E^(α^2/ω) Sqrt[π] Erfc[α/
            Sqrt[ω]] + (8 E^(α^2/ω) Sqrt[π] \
α^2 Erfc[α/
              Sqrt[ω]])/ω))/(-4 α Sqrt[ω] + 
       2 E^(α^2/ω) Sqrt[π] (2 α^2 + ω) Erfc[\
α/Sqrt[ω]]) - (ω (-4 Sqrt[ω] + 
         3 Sqrt[π] ω + 
         4 E^(α^2/ω) Sqrt[π] α Erfc[α/
            Sqrt[ω]]) (-4 Sqrt[ω] - (4 (2 α^2 + \
ω))/Sqrt[ω] + 
         8 E^(α^2/ω) Sqrt[π] α Erfc[α/
            Sqrt[ω]] + (4 E^(α^2/ω) Sqrt[π] α \
(2 α^2 + ω) Erfc[α/
              Sqrt[ω]])/ω))/(-4 α Sqrt[ω] + 
        2 E^(α^2/ω) Sqrt[π] (2 α^2 + ω) Erfc[\
α/Sqrt[ω]])^2 // Simplify;
```

To gain insight,

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[da, {ω, 0, ωmax}, {α, 0, αmax},
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {ω, α}),
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, All,
    LegendLabel -> HoldForm[da]],
  ScalingFunctions -> If[LogLinear, {"Log", None}, None],
  WorkingPrecision -> 15,
  PlotPoints -> 50],
 {{αmax, 10, Subscript[α, max]}, 1, 50, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ωmax, 5000, Subscript[ω, max]}, 100, 10000, 100, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{LogLinear, True}, {True, False}},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Your plot is quite confusing since roots  as a dependence $\alpha(\omega)$ is a decrising function and it is positive for $\omega < 0.025$.

Comment: @Artes - The lines in the plot are not plots of `α[ω]`, they are isoclines of `da` in the `{ω, α}` plane. For small `ω`, `Asymptotic[da, ω -> 0]` is `(9*Sqrt[Pi]*α^2)/(2*Sqrt[ω])` For small `ω`, turn off the `LogLinear` scaling.

Comment: I know. I've suggested that for $\omega>0.025$ roots are negative and so this plot is not especially required.

Answer (score 3):

Working with functions involving products of the error  and the exponential functions  `Erfc[x] Exp[x^2]` we have to take care of possible issues with numerical underflows  and overflows e.g. [Numerical underflow for a scaled error function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3854/numerical-underflow-for-a-scaled-error-function).

Taking `Simplify[da]` for `da` from the question we can rewrite the given expression  in more readable form

```
Clear[da] 
da[α_, ω_]:= ( ω( -8 ω + 6 Sqrt[π] Sqrt[ω](α^2 + ω) 
   - 3 Exp[α^2/ω] Sqrt[π] α ( -4 Sqrt[ω] + Sqrt[π]( 2α^2 + 3ω))Erfc[ α/Sqrt[ω]] 
   - 2 Exp[ 2α^2/ω] π ( 2α^2 - ω) Erfc[ α/Sqrt[ω]]^2))/( -2α Sqrt[ω] 
  + Exp[α^2/ω] Sqrt[π]( 2α^2 + ω) Erfc[ α/Sqrt[ω]])^2
```

Then we can define  a symbolic solution as a function of `ω`

```
αs[ω_] /; ω > 0 := SolveValues[ da[ α, ω] == 0 && -2 < α < 2, α] // First
```

To obtain solutions we have added a condition `-2 < α < 2`. Restriction can be weakened, however  time for searching solutions can become longer. This is an exact solution and it can be transformed symbolically, see e.g. [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768)

```
αs[1] // InputForm
```

> ```
> Root[{8 - 6 Sqrt[π] - 2 E^(2 #1^2) π Erfc[#1]^2 - 12 E^#1^2 Sqrt[π] Erfc[#1] #1
>       + 9 E^#1^2 π Erfc[#1] #1 - 6 Sqrt[π] #1^2 + 4 E^(2#1^2) π Erfc[#1]^2 #1^2
>       + 6 E^#1^2 π Erfc[#1] #1^3 & , -0.97626785523387043309}]
> ```

In this case the `Root` object cannot be simplified further and it means in general that it is the best symbolic solution we can get unless we know what kind of transformations of the error function we need, see e.g. `Entity["MathematicalFunction", "Erfc"]["Dataset"]` or [Can the error function be expressed in terms of other special functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/229939/can-the-error-function-be-expressed-in-terms-of-other-special-functions)

We can evaluate a solution with an arbitrary precission:

```
N[ αs[1], 50]
```

> ```
> -0.97626785523387043308947964541495694018253443102687
> ```

Nevertheless we can exploit the symbolic power of the system to get an insight in the behaviour  of the function. One can observe that it is reasonable to use a variable `x == α/Sqrt[ω]` to recast the function in a simpler form:

```
da[ x Sqrt[ω], ω] // Simplify
```

[image]

We can e.g. find the asymptotic behaviour of the function

```
Asymptotic[ da[x , 1], {x, Infinity, 6}] // N
```

> ```
> 6.97604 + 1084.45/x^6 - 104.713/x^4 + 7.48203/x^2 + 7.97604 x^2
> ```

and let's add a graphical representation of solutions:

```
Plot[{da[α, 1], da[α, 1/2], da[α, 1/5]}, {α, -3/2, 1/5}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point[{{αs[1], 0}, {αs[1/2], 0}, {αs[1/5], 0}}]}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

and  the graph of the function `αs[ω]` compared to its asymptotic form

```
asd = Asymptotic[da[α, ω], {α, 0, 3}]
ContourPlot[{da[α, ω] == 0, asd == 0}, {ω, 0.01, 16}, {α, -6.7, 0.2}, 
  ContourStyle -> {{Thickness[0.009], Cyan}, {DotDashed, Magenta}}]
```

[image]

[image]